# Bad request (400) when using PutAsJsonAsync if Model has navigation properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, blazor

I am creating a simple API and I have a method that handles the update of a game:

```
    [HttpPut("{Id}")]
    public bool UpdateGame(Guid Id, [FromBody] Game game)
    {
        Game? oldGame = _unitOfWork.Games.GetById(Id);
        if (oldGame != null)
        {
            oldGame.SeasonId = game.SeasonId;
            oldGame.VenueId = game.VenueId;
            oldGame.GameTypeId = game.GameTypeId;
            oldGame.GameTitle = game.GameTitle;
            oldGame.GameDateTime = game.GameDateTime;
            oldGame.PublishResults = game.PublishResults;
            oldGame.GameDetails = game.GameDetails;
            oldGame.Buyin = game.Buyin;
            oldGame.Fee = game.Fee;
            _unitOfWork.Save();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I have tests against the repo and the controller and the update works fine.

I'm now implementing some CRUD pages using Blazor Server:

```
    async Task OnSubmit()
    {
        if (Game != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await _apiClient.httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync<Game>($"/api/Games/{Id}", Game);
                bool updated = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<bool>();

                if (updated)
                {
                    _navManager.NavigateTo("/settings/games");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AlertIsVisible = true;
                Message = ex.Message;
                MessageType = AlertMessageType.Danger;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is failing because of a bad request 400, but this is all the output is telling me. The put method in the controller doesn't hit as my breakpoint doesn't trigger.

Simpler models in my app post just fine using similar code.

The difference here I believe is this Game entity:

```
public class Game
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? SeasonId { get; set; }
    public Guid? GameTypeId { get; set; }
    public Guid? VenueId { get; set; }
    public string? GameTitle { get; set; }
    public DateTime GameDateTime { get; set; }
    public bool PublishResults { get; set; }
    public string? GameDetails { get; set; }
    public double Buyin { get; set; }
    public double Fee { get; set; }

    public virtual Season Season { get; set; } = default!;
    public virtual GameType GameType { get; set; } = default!;
    public virtual Venue Venue { get; set; } = default!;
    public virtual ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; } = new HashSet<Result>();
}
```

I think there is a serialisation issue with the navigation properties (`Season`, `GameType` and `Venue` - not the `Results` collection). If I remove the navigation properties the update succeeds. I'm at a loss at this point on how to handle the put request so that it works with the navigation properties on my model.

Comment: You may have a property in one of the objects that isn't serializable.  You also declare Season as not nullable (no ?) and then forcibly set it to `default!`, which for any object will be null.  You normally use `default!` when you know an object will be set to a value before any attempt is made to use it.

Comment: That's it! And let that be a lesson for copying and pasting legacy code out of older projects! If I removed the default assignment and make the properties nullable, that fixes the problem. If you'd like to offer it as the answer I'll mark it accordingly.

Comment: I will do so now

Comment: btw, it's a rarity on here to see people using nullability properly!

Comment: Thanks Shaun. And thanks for your website. I've just seen it via your profile and I've read articles there in the past. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare Season, GameType and Venue as not `Nullable` [no ?], and then forcibly set to default!, which for any object is null.

You normally use `default!` when you know an object will be set to a value before any attempt is made to use it, which is not the case here.

Comment: Wish I could give you a +100 for this.  It was a very obscure problem and hard to track down.